# Objective C, UIGestureRecognizer allocation and release

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i'm new to obj-c and i was just wondering if someone could explain this.  Here we add a UIGestureRecognizer to the current view, and then we release it right away, why?  If we release it will this not make it useless in the program?

```
recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

((UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer).minimumNumberOfTouches = 3;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

[recognizer release];
```

Comment: "Mammary management"? Is that for when everything goes tits-up?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but Objective-C isn't going to allow you to manage mammaries in the least - you'll have to do that on your own. ;) (For the record, the question was originally titled 'Mammary management in Objective-C'.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

the gesture recognizer retain count is increased. So, the following `release` just counter-balances the alloc/init action, which returns an object with retain count of 1.

In other words, you can think in these terms:

1. alloc -> retains the object;
2. addGestureRecognizer -> retains the object;

since you want that `self.view` be the only owner of the gesture recognizer, you call `release` once to get things back in order. When `self.view` is deallocated, it will call release on its gesture recognizer and this will be deallocated as well.

If you did not do like that, you would have a memory leak, since when self.view is deallocated, `release` would be called on the gesture recognizer but this would not be enough to make the retain count drop to zero (because of the initial `retain` implied by `alloc`).

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS there is something called (retain count) this is an internal counter that is used to keep track of all references used by the objects or object has .. so every time you make (alloc, copy, retain) to the object it will increase its retain counter by 1 .. in those three cases you are responsible to (release) the object which will decrease the counter also by 1 .. in your case you made the right thing to release the object but it didn't deallocated because when you add it to the view its retain counter increased by 1 so its still in the memory but you are not responsible to remove it iOS will do that for you (autoreleased). hope this will be helpful. good luck.